# Extract specific pattern (4 digits, '-', 1digit) from string in R

Tags: regex, r

Imagine following string:

```
x <- "aokizoizeon1854-1zeoijzeoinq1234-2zeze
```

I want to extract from this string '1854-1' and '1234-2'. So basically every part of the string that consists of 4 digits followed by a '-' and again one digit.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: You just explained the pattern, isn't it the easiest way? A digit is `[0-9]`. 4 digits: `[0-9]{4}`. Use `str_extract_all`. Unless you have strings like `asdf123534-2324defe`, this is really easy.

Comment: you can try package `stringr` like  `stringr::str_extract_all(x, "[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]" )`

Comment: @MamounBenghezal: Yes, under one condition (see my comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str_extract_all` from stringr package with a PCRE regex.

In case your strings can contain digit sequences longer than 4 and you want to just match *exactly* 4 digit sequences followed with a hyphen and then *exactly* one digit, you will need *lookarounds* to precise the matches:

```
> library(stringr)
> x <- "aokizoizeon1854-1zeoijzeoinq1234-2zeze12445664-345ff"
> unlist(str_extract_all(x, "(?<!\\d)\\d{4}-\\d(?!\\d)"))
[1] "1854-1" "1234-2"
```

The `(?<!\\d)\\d{4}-\\d(?!\\d)` regex matches:

- `(?<!\\d)` - fail the match if there is a digit before the current position
- `\\d{4}-\\d` - match 4 digits followed with a hyphen and 1 digit
- `(?!\\d)` - but fail the match if that one digit is followed with another digit.

Answer (score 3):

A possible `base` solution could be to get rid of all the characters then split the numbers into separate strings:

```
x1 <- gsub("[a-z]", "", x)
substring(x1, seq(1,nchar(x1),6), seq(6, nchar(x1), 6))
#[1] "1854-1" "1234-2"
```

Comment: Again, this will not work with input like `aokizoizeon1854-1zeoijzeoinq1234-2zeze12445664-345ff` (output: `[1] "1854-1" "1234-2" "124456" "64-345"`)

Comment: true, the above assumes that the strings to be extracted are surrounded by alphabetic characters on both sides, as in the example string.